# Showing fields depending on parent object

Tags: object

On my opportunity object I have a picklist called "Industry" which has two values: Bldg, Terr.
I have a custom related list on opportunity which has fields FieldA, FieldB and FieldC.

1. When the user selects "BLDG" in Industry picklist of opportunity and then creates a record of my custom object, I want to only display FieldA and FieldB.
2. When the user selects "TERR" in the Industry picklist, I want the related object to only show FieldC.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the visible columns in the related list OR in the object view OR both?

Comment: In a less code-specific manner (gasp!), and if you don't already have many record types in use, you can use two different record types with two different related list layouts.  Then use a workflow rule that adjusts the record type based on the picklist value.  The end result is relatively invisible to the end user, but the related list layout is customized decoratively.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Using VF page this can be done. you can emebed this page on standard page layout.

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!displayFieldA__c}">
     <td>Field A</td>
</apex:outputText>


<apex:outputText rendered="{!displayFieldB__c}">
         <td>Field B</td>
</apex:outputText>

<apex:outputText rendered="{!displayFieldC__c}">
         <td>Field C</td>
</apex:outputText>
```

Apex Class :

```
boolean displayFieldA__c = false;
boolean displayFieldB__c = false;
boolean displayFieldC__c = false;


 IF(Opp.industry__c == 'BLDG'){
       displayFieldA__c = true;
       displayFieldB__c = true;
    }


 IF(Opp.industry__c == 'TERR''){
           displayFieldC__c = true;
        }
```

Hope you find it useful :-)